# How to hoist non react statics with typescript and styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a static three static properties (`Header`, `Body`, and `Footer`) set to a `Dialog` component. However, typescript throws the following error after wrapping the `Dialog` component in styled-components.

`Property 'Header' does not exist on type 'StyledComponentClass...`

Here is my `/Dialog.tsx`:

```
import { Dialog as BlueprintDialog, IDialogProps } from '@blueprintjs/core';
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import Body from './Dialog.Body';
import Footer from './Dialog.Footer';
import Header from './Dialog.Header';

/** ************************************************************************* */

type DefaultProps = {
  className: string;
};

export interface DialogProps extends IDialogProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  primary?: boolean;
}

class Dialog extends React.PureComponent<DialogProps> {
  static displayName = 'UI.Dialog';
  static defaultProps: DefaultProps = {
    className: '',
  };
  static Body: typeof Body;
  static Footer: typeof Footer;
  static Header: typeof Header;
  render() {
    return <BlueprintDialog {...this.props} />;
  }
}

/** ************************************************************************* */

export default styled(Dialog)``;
```

And here is my `index.ts` where I piece it all together:

```
import Dialog from './Dialog';
import DialogBody from './Dialog.Body';
import DialogFooter from './Dialog.Footer';
import DialogHeader from './Dialog.Header';

Dialog.Body = DialogBody; // TS Compilation Error :/
Dialog.Footer = DialogFooter; // TS Compilation Error :/
Dialog.Header = DialogHeader; // TS Compilation Error :/
export default Dialog;
```

I've tried doing the following, which works, but now interpolation fails for the root `Dialog` component:

```
import { Dialog as BlueprintDialog, IDialogProps } from '@blueprintjs/core';
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import Body from './Dialog.Body';
import Footer from './Dialog.Footer';
import Header from './Dialog.Header';

/** ************************************************************************* */

type DefaultProps = {
  className: string;
};

export interface DialogProps extends IDialogProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  primary?: boolean;
}

class Dialog extends React.PureComponent<DialogProps> {
  static displayName = 'UI.Dialog';
  static defaultProps: DefaultProps = {
    className: '',
  };
  render() {
    return <BlueprintDialog {...this.props} />;
  }
}

/** ************************************************************************* */

const Styled = styled(Dialog)``;

class WithSubmodules extends Styled {
  static Body: typeof Body;
  static Footer: typeof Footer;
  static Header: typeof Header;
}

export default WithSubmodules;
```

An example of interpolation that throws the `Cannot call a class as a function` error:

```
export default styled(InterpolationExample)`
  ${Dialog.Header} { /* WORKS :) */
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  ${Dialog} { { /* Throws Error :/ */
    border: 1px solid pink;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some tinkering and got something to work. If anybody has a better approach then please let me know!

What I ended up doing is importing the `StyledComponentClass` from `styled-components`, then extending it with static properties in the following way:

```
interface WithSubmodules extends StyledComponentClass<DialogProps, {}> {
  Body: typeof Body;
  Footer: typeof Footer;
  Header: typeof Header;
}
```

Next, I cast the returned `StyledComponent` to my new extended type, `WithSubmodules`:

```
export default styled(Dialog)`` as WithSubmodules;
```

Here is everything together:

```
import { Dialog as BlueprintDialog, IDialogProps } from '@blueprintjs/core';
import * as React from 'react';
import styled, { StyledComponentClass } from 'styled-components';

import Body from './Dialog.Body';
import Footer from './Dialog.Footer';
import Header from './Dialog.Header';

/** ************************************************************************* */

type DefaultProps = {
  className: string;
};

export interface DialogProps extends IDialogProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  primary?: boolean;
}

class Dialog extends React.PureComponent<DialogProps> {
  static displayName = 'UI.Dialog';
  static defaultProps: DefaultProps = {
    className: '',
  };
  render() {
    return <BlueprintDialog {...this.props} />;
  }
}

/** ************************************************************************* */

interface WithSubmodules extends StyledComponentClass<DialogProps, {}> {
  Body: typeof Body;
  Footer: typeof Footer;
  Header: typeof Header;
}

export default styled(Dialog)`` as WithSubmodules;
```

Again, if anyone has a better approach then let me know!

Thanks